# I am unable to see all the possible badges, where can I find them?

Tags: support, badges, badge-tracking

I am trying to look for the Unsung Hero Gold badge. First, I go to my profile on the main MSE and go to activity. Then, I hit the gear icon here to get to the badge area

[image]

Here I am!

[image]

Now, I hit the gold section, but I can't see the Unsung Hero badge. Where is it?

[image]

Comment: I think the screens you're looking at show only Participation badges, not Question badges, but I might be wrong.  Someone else will know for certain.  In the meantime however, the Help Centre lists all the badges excluding the individual tag badges, which are site-specific: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: @postmortes Yes, but I need them in my tracker so that I will be able to earn them

Comment: No you don't.  If you meet the criteria for them you'll earn them :)  Unsung Hero is something that would be exceptionally hard to try and "earn" given that it would require you answering questions with the hope that they were accepted but not upvoted (by anyone!)

Comment: [meta.se]: [Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263610)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks this is really helpful